# Capture Alias Command Names into Array. Then Execute each in a For Loop

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, alias

Trying to dynamically capture a list of specific alias commands, and store for execution later in the script. I want to dynamically capture, since this script will run against multiple users on multiple servers with different commands. IE: server1 might have 'statcmd1', 2 and 3; while server2 will only have 'statcmd2'. There is more to it, but this is where I am stuck. I'm guessing something isnt right with how the array is being set? Maybe there is another way to do this.

**Test:**

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.bash_profile    #Aliases are set in here

# Capture the set aliases into array. It will omit the actual command and only pick up the alias name.
ALL_STAT=($(alias | grep "control.sh" | awk '{print $2}'| awk -F '=' '{print $1}' | grep -F "stat"))

#Execute the status of all elements listed in the array
for i in ${ALL_STAT[@]}; do $i; done
```

**Execution:**

```
[user@server]$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 16: statcmd1: command not found
./test.sh: line 16: statcmd2: command not found
./test.sh: line 16: statcmd3: command not found
```

**Execute Alias Commands Outside of Script Works:**

```
[user@server]$ statcmd1
RUNNING
[user@server]$ statcmd2
RUNNING
[user@server]$ statcmd3
RUNNING
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the bash manpage:

> Aliases  are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless
>   the expand_aliases shell option is set using shopt (see the
>   description  of shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).

Execute

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

before executing the commands - afterwards, all aliases are also available in the script.

Furthermore, due to the fact that alias expansion takes place before variable expansion, the line has to be evaluated twice with the help of `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $HOME/.bash_profile    #Aliases are set in here

# Capture the set aliases into array. It will omit the actual command and only pick up the alias name.
ALL_STAT=($(alias | grep "control.sh" | awk '{print $2}'| awk -F '=' '{print $1}' | grep -F "stat"))

shopt -s expand_aliases
#Execute the status of all elements listed in the array
for i in ${ALL_STAT[@]}
do
    eval "$i"
done
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I was playing with eval as well a few minutes but couldnt get it right. The aliases have already been expanded system wide, but I'll add it to the script for peace of mind (and a reminder that it's needed for this.)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation), alias expansion is performed **prior** to variable expansion. Therefore the expansion of `$i` is not even attempted to be expanded as an alias.

You can use functions instead. Command/function execution is performed **after** variable expansion. As a matter of fact, the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Aliases) also says:

> For almost every purpose, shell functions are preferred over aliases.